# Call to undefined function user_load() using Drupal 9 and api3?

Tags: api, drupal-8

Full error message:

```
Error: Call to undefined function user_load() in CRM_Utils_System_DrupalBase->getUserObject() (line 558 of /var/www/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/System/DrupalBase.php)
```

I get this when using an api3 call like this:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('User', 'get', [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'id' => 1,
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function user_load is deprecated in D9.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/8.7.x

Looks like we need a replacement stub function in the drupal module. For a quick hack, you could append this to /var/www/drupal/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/civicrm.module (or wherever it lives on your server).

A better method might be to create a new D9 file of functions that gets loaded selectively only for D9.

```
/* for when user_load gets deprecated */

if (!function_exists('user_load')) {

function user_load($uid, $reset = FALSE) {
  if ($reset) {
    \Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getStorage('user')
      ->resetCache([
      $uid,
    ]);
  }
  return \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
}

}
```

Comment: Put that into a PR and we'll all vote it up!

Comment: @alan-dixon I have created a PR which basically does that but in a different way which should cover D8 and D9 https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19517 but yours got be on the right direction

Comment: you beat me by 30 seconds https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19518

Comment:  Thank you!